# Query users having "Manage Content Permissions" OR "Manage Salesforce CRM Content" permission

Tags: soql, permissions, content

I am trying to find out the API name and respective object where these permission are stored?
"Manage Content Permissions" OR "Manage Salesforce CRM Content"

I was able to find the "UserPermissionsSFContentUser" on User object but this looks like permission where a user can use Salesforce Content.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`PermissionsManageContentPermissions` & `PermissionsContentAdministrator` can be used to retrieve those two app permissions from the PermissionSet object.

```
select Id,
    PermissionsManageContentPermissions,
    PermissionsContentAdministrator
from PermissionSet
where <CustomFilter>
```

Comment: OP wants users possessing these permissions - one needs to query PermissionSetAssignment if I'm not mistaken

Comment: In addition you would wan to see what profiles have this permission and include users with those profiles.